# Making a successful Bluetooth Connection to RPi

Tags: python, bluetooth

I have a RPi and a normal Debian on my pc, both using the Bluetooth Python module to communicate. Both have some Bluetooth USB dongle in them.
I can use the pc as server and the RPi as client, this connection works very well. However I'm not able to do it vice versa, I checked my `rfcomm.conf` and `main.conf`, but both seem to be ok.
Any other pitfalls?

---

```
#Server.py

import bluetooth

server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

port = 1
server_sock.bind(("",port))
server_sock.listen(1)

client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ",address

data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print "received [%s]" % data

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

---

```
#Client.py

import bluetooth

bd_addr = #myspecificmacaddress

port = 1

sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((bd_addr, port))

sock.send("hello!!")

sock.close()
```

---

So to be more precise: Running `Client.py` on RPi and `Server.py` on pc works fine, doing vice versa, obviously with corrected MAC, simply says: `bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (112, 'Host is down')`

Comment: Just to mention it: I tried running the server as root, too, but same behavior.

Comment: `l2ping` is successful from both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that my config files weren't that well. (it must had to do something with config files)

`/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` has a class section. `/var/lib/bluetooth/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/config` has a class section, too.

I do not know why, I do not know how or what is actually happening, as you are not able to find anything about this on the internet, but setting *both* to `0x400100` fixed it. I don't know if they just have to match or if it's some special thing I came up by fortune, but it works and I dont really want to possibly break it again.

Maybe someone with more knowledge about this is willing to improve my answer here.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but just for other people who might need it, same thing happened to me, so I just had to do:

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
```

And now it becomes discoverable and able to send and receive data