# can't connect a socket to bluetooth paired device

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, hc-05

I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi 3B to an Arduino that has an HC-05 bluetooth chip to send commands.
I have successfully paired between the HC-05 and the Pi using

```sh
Device 98:7B:F3:57:76:34
    Name: BT05
    Alias: BT05
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Unknown                   (0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: bluetooth:v000Dp0000d0110
```

Now I'm trying to use Python to send commands. My code is:

```py
import bluetooth

bd_addr = "98:7B:F3:57:76:34"

def connect ():
    port = 1
    sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    print("Trying to pair to", bd_addr)
    sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
    a = "a"
    while a != 'quit':
        a = input("<<< ")
        sock.send(a)
    sock.close()

connect()
```

I get an exception while running the code, saying that the host is down, and I can't find the problem:

```sh
python3 tests/bt.py 
Trying to pair to 98:7B:F3:57:76:34
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in connect
_bluetooth.error: (112, 'Host is down')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/bt.py", line 16, in <module>
    connect()
  File "tests/bt.py", line 9, in connect
    sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
  File "<string>", line 5, in connect
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (112, 'Host is down')
```

I've tried replacing the HC-05 device and restarting the bluetooth service, and the Pi but I still can't seem to connect to Arduino, and I'm lost.

Thanks to all helpers

Comment: Before connecting, try checking if the host where you start the connection from has it's bluetooth interface up. If not, manually put it up. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123540/making-a-successful-bluetooth-connection-to-rpi) thread has a couple of answers that could help.

Comment: @BoboDarph Wow! Thanks! it really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by doing 2 things:
First of all, only one out of my 5 HC-05 modules is OK, which made solving the other half of the issue very hard.

The other solution came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123540/making-a-successful-bluetooth-connection-to-rpi) post. 
I changed the class section in

```
/etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

to:

```
Class = 0x400100
```

And that's it. I don't even need to pair my device after a reboot (of the Arduino or the Pi). This code connects the Pi and the Arduino and sends all commands.

Comment: I think Class 0x400100 tells your interface that your BT device is a Computer with Telephony capabilities. See [this](http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html) page for more details. I guess it would make no sense for your development board's bt interface to retain pairing information otherwise.